# How to create a webpage kit with drag and drop support

Tags: drag-and-drop

How hard would it be to create a website that lets people create their own pages on them?

Like a company creating a custom page on my site only with a drag and drop system provided by my website (of course they would need to create an account).

What frameworks would I need to use?

I tried searching the web but didn't find anything. I found `craft.js` but I don't know if I can implement it like that.

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Such a project would be very complex and cannot simply be "coded down". Here are the main reasons:

- You need an infrastructure where and how your users can save their websites. Does every user just have one page or several (limited or unlimited)?
- Drag and Drop requires some JavaScript interactions and a set of predefined web components like buttons, input fields, labels or images. You would have to define abstract components that could be individually filled with user content.
- If you ask your users to register before creating websites, you must respect the "[General Data Protection Regulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Data_Protection_Regulation)" (applies for the European Union).
- If you want to make money with your project you'll have to consider several legal aspects depending on the country where you live.

In short, there are many reasons why homepage kits are not an easy thing to program.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, it was just an idea, firm would be just an example but no firm would need a website like that